# R - coerce geom_density() in ggplot2 to accept a df column as the frequency (y-variable)

Tags: r, ggplot2, geom-bar

I am attempting to make a smoothed histogram using `geom_density` in `ggplot2`. The problem is, technically what I am making is not exactly a histogram, so I am running into trouble. Specifically, along the x-axis of the desired plot is genomic position, but the values can start and end anywhere. Moreover, the y-axis is not exactly counts, but rather is contents of a numeric vector in the df, locus_df_trim$V7, which for my data is an intensity value ranging between 0 and 266.

The "bins" corresponding to each observation may be different numbers of base pairs long, so there are no uniform bin sizes, and there also may be breaks between bins.

I have not been able to get ggplot to accept anything resembling locus_trim_df$V7 as a y-value. Also, if I let the value = ..scaled.., it is not correct because the intensity values are not proportional to the number of observations (which is what drives the ..scaled.. and ..count.. variables if I specify them).

So, at this point my only idea is to recreate the dataframe itself so that there are uniform bin sizes, and each observation for each cell type that does not have an intensity receives a 0 in the df. However, I am wondering if there is a way to produce the desired plot using a df of the current form, which is:

```
head(locus_df_trim)
> head(locus_df_trim)
                     V2       V3        V5  V7 annot_width
1 CD4+_CD25-_IL17-_PMA-  H3K27ac 204738970 103        1042
2 CD4+_CD25-_IL17-_PMA-  H3K27ac 204738517  40         250
3 CD4+_CD25-_IL17-_PMA- H3K36me3 204738136 158         515
4 CD4+_CD25-_IL17-_PMA- H3K36me3 204738702 104         709
5 CD4+_CD25-_IL17+  H3K4me1 204738665 226        1246
6 CD4+_CD25-_IL17+  H3K4me1 204741441  73         397
...
43 Tmem_Primary_Cells  H3K27ac 204738908  34         390
44 Tmem_Primary_Cells H3K27me3 204738382  28         194
45 Tmem_Primary_Cells  H3K4me1 204738766 124         424
46 Tmem_Primary_Cells  H3K4me1 204741433  48         423
47 Tmem_Primary_Cells  H3K4me1 204739411  40         215
48 Tmem_Primary_Cells  H3K4me1 204737304  33         210
```

I am able to produce a plot that is close to what is desired, but trying to specify the y-value to be proportional to V7 (as below) results in the error:

```
 Error in eval(substitute(list(...)), `_data`, parent.frame()) : 
  object 'y' not found
```

To be clear, the desired plot has the following attributes:

I want to make a smoothed histogram with the following features:

- the bin for a given observation begins at the x-coordinate of a value found in one column, and ends at the value found in another column
- each cell type (in column locus_trim_df$V2 below) has a different color)
- the height of each peak (in the y-direction) is proportional to the value in a column of the df (locus_df_trim$V7).

so far I have the following code:

```
library("ggplot2")

base_plot<-ggplot(data=locus_df_trim, aes(x=V5, y=V7, fill=V2, size=V7)) + geom_density(alpha=0.3, adjust=0.4, kernel="gaussian")
base_plot<-base_plot + geom_vline(xintercept = 204738919, size = 1, colour = "#FF3721", linetype = "dashed")
base_plot<-base_plot + theme_classic(); base_plot
```

by contrast, the following code does not error and produces a plot similar to what is desired, but suffers from miscalibrated bin placement and incorrect height for the peaks in the y-direction:

base_plot<-ggplot(data=locus_df_trim, aes(x=V5, fill=V2)) + geom_density(alpha=0.3, adjust=0.4, kernel="gaussian")
base_plot<-base_plot + geom_vline(xintercept = 204738919, size = 1, colour = "#FF3721", linetype = "dashed")
base_plot<-base_plot + theme_classic(); base_plot

[image: misspecified plot]

Comment: Can you give some example of what you want with an example dataset? or an image of something similar? as described this is very confusing - your "bins" sound more like groups if they aren't continuous variables on the X

Comment: yes they are 100% groups.  i was hoping the snippet of `locus_df_trim` would be enough to help people see the data. But I can make the dataset if you think you will have time to tackle.

thank you very much for your response.